# Converting and concatenating doubles into byte arrays

Tags: c++, tcp, double, arrays

I am trying to send various data of type double through a TCP network, and would like to convert all this data as a single byte-array. Any suggestions that also handle possible differences in endianness?

This is what I tried, but the correct values are not stored in the array:

```
// Byte-array
char buf[MAX_SIZE];
// Data
double data1, data2, data3, ... ;

// Convert and store all data
uint64_t d1 = htole64(data1);
memcpy(buf, &d1, sizeof(d1));

uint64_t d2 = htole64(data2);
memcpy(buf+8, &d2, sizeof(d2));

uint64_t d3 = htole64(data3);
memcpy(buf+16, &d3, sizeof(d3));
...
```

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

htole64 takes an uint64_t with host order bytes and converts it to an uint64_t with little-endian bytes.  If you pass a double, it will be cast to an integer64 first, which I assume is not what you want.

You probably want to do something like this:

```
uint64_t d1 = htole64( *(uint64_t*)(&data1) );
```

Although I won't be surprised if that violates some C++ aliasing rules.